# How to display Label and UI-Slider-Range in Single Line

Tags: ajax, uislider, jquery-ui-slider

I am using slider-range with Label. So it is looking like as

```
Time 12:00am to 5:00pm
here my slider-range is displaying
```

I am trying it move up to slider with Label so it will be in single Line.
Expect result:-

```
Time 12:00am to 5:00pm here my slider-range is displaying
```

This code I am using.

```
<div id="time-range" class="padTopBottom10">
<p>Time : <span class="slider-time">12:00 AM</span> - <span class="slider-time2">05:00 PM</span></p>
<div class="sliders_step1">
    <div id="slider-range"></div>
</div>
```

please anyone help me.

Answer (score 1):

your `<p>` and your `<div>` tags are both block-elements, you need to set them to be `display: inline-block;` in your CSS :)